# Share deep link from web not taking title in google plus

Tags: javascript

I have implemented sharing functionality in my page. However it is working fine with other social media but not quite well with google plus. It is not showing any description or image. Here is screenshot

[image]

```
var generateShareUrl = function (data) {
    switch (data.socialMediaType.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'facebook':
        return {
          url: 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=' + encodeURI(data.shareUrl) +
          '&p[images][0]=' + data.imageUrl +
          '&p[title]=' + '' +
          '&p[summary]=' + data.text,
          target: 'facebook-share-dialog'
        };
      case 'googleplus':
        return {
          url: 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + encodeURI(data.shareUrl) + '&title=Colors Stardust Awards 2015',
          target: ''
        };
      case 'twitter':
        return {
          url: 'https://twitter.com/share?url=' + encodeURI(data.shareUrl) + '&text=' + encodeURI(data.title),
          target: ''
        };
      case 'linkedin':
        return {
          url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURI(data.shareUrl) +
          '&title=' + '' +
          '&summary=' + data.title +
          '&source=' + '',
          target: ''
        };
    }
  };

  share.shareThisUrl = function (data) {
    var share = generateShareUrl(data);
    window.open(share.url, share.target, 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    return false;
  };
```

Comment: Did you add OpenGraph tags to the head of your page?

Comment: yes I had added but it did not work

Comment: I think google is trying to get info from deep link

Comment: Can you please add your OpenGraph tags to your question?